# Music with brutal and high variations of tempo and/or sound level and/or pitch

Tags: classical-music

I try to give a hand to a friend who is preparing a talk about borderline personality in psychology.

Particularly, she was thinking to highlight the emotional distress and instability with some particular song with "some kind of peaks" in it.

The critical section would ideally last max 2-3 min, and maybe suggest huge joy, before to fall into deep and dark sadness very quickly, before to revert to another feeling with extremely high intensity.

To give an example, she had considered the final piano performance in '4 minutes' movie (but extracted from the movie, its emotional footprint was lower than expected). I have indicated classical music to set a tag to the question, but it is not required.

Any idea of music you've heard of, so that we should give it a try?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this as the is not only primary opinion based, but too broad.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly not classical, but your question led my mind directly to this track:

[Stubb (A Dub)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RBSrUtX0bA) by Mr Bungle off of their self-titled debut album.

> Mr. Bungle was an American experimental band from Eureka, California. The band was formed in 1985 while the members were still in high school, and was named after a 1950s children's educational film regarding bad habits which was later featured in a 1981 Pee-wee Herman HBO special...
>   Mr. Bungle was known for its distinctive musical traits, often cycling through several musical genres within the course of a single song.
>   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Bungle

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure it would make a suitable illustration for your friend, but it fits the description:

*[The Most Unwanted Music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gPuH1yeZ08)*

This song was created by artists Komar and Melamid and composer Dave Soldier in 1997 with the goal of including a wide range of elements that people, according to a survey, disliked in their music, including sudden changes of mood and tempo.

Outside of that, my other best suggestion would be Bjork's *[It's Oh So Quiet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htobTBlCvUU)*.  You could also look into the music of [Daniel Johnston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Johnston) who actually (I believe) has borderline personality disorder.

Comment: Good call on the Bjork. She was the first to pop into my mind when reading this question.

Answer (score 1):

You might find interesting things in breakcore music and electronica.
[Venetian Snares - Hajnal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbJ63spk48s),
[Aphex Twin - Windowlicker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fmo1Sjn7dg) also go check for 
Toe Cutter and 
Xanopticon's work.
Cheers

Comment: I agree on both artists listed - they have very extreme and fast-changing music patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Or the symphonies of Gustav Mahler:  try the final movement from Symphony #6!

Answer (score 1):

Try "Arms" by Genghis Tron, it's a mixture of thrash and electronic music with abrupt, heavy changes.

Answer (score 0):

["In My Time Of Dying"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZgblTKscX0) - Led Zeppelin

It's an 11-minute long rollercoaster.

Answer (score 0):

An orchestral answer would be:
I. Stravinsky "Le Sacre du printemps" Part II.